# Python Pandas extract with regex using OR expression

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have the following document, where it consists of multiple headers(bolded ones), and the corresponding text.

**Major Contribution of Bananas:** 
blah blah1 
 
**History of Monkey:** 
blah blah2 
 
**Why apple is better than banana:** 
blah blah3

...

I have multiple documents of this type, and I want to extract text by its headers. For now, I am focusing on "History of monkey:" section, so I am trying to extract "blah blah 2." The problem is that some of these documents have typos and different versions, that the same header is written differently. i.e. "Grand History of Monkey:" or "Really Awesome History of Monkey:" or "16 Interesting facts of Monkey:" and so on. The good thing is that it mostly ends in "of Monkey:", except for some of them which goes like "Monkey facts:", "Monkey Info:"

To freely utilize "." in regex, I have changed all \n to \\n before applying regex, and am using the following pattern.

```
li = ["Monkey facts:", "Monkey Info", "Interesting facts of Monkey:"]
sections = '|'.join(li)
notes_ds.TEXT.str.extract(r'(?i)\\n(?:{})(.+?)\\n\\n[^(\\|\d|\.)]+?:'.format(sections)),
```

But in this way, I can't capture the text for all headers ending in "of Monkey".
How could I possibly change the pattern to solve this issue?

Comment: "*To freely utilize "." in regex, I have changed all \n to \\n before applying regex*" - this is not going to help much, when you have line breaks, `.` can match all them with `re.DOTALL` / `re.S` option or `(?s)` / `(?s:...)` inline constructs. What about splitting with two line breaks (to get paragraphs), and then check what text is at the start of each paragraph? E.g. `pars = re.split(r'(?:\r?\n){2,}', text)` and then you can use `[par for par in pars if any(par.startswith(p) for p in li)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can split the text with two line break sequences to get separate paragraphs, and then check the text at the start of each paragraph.

Sample Python code:

```py
li = ["Monkey facts:", "Monkey Info", "Interesting facts of Monkey:"]
pars = re.split(r'(?:\r?\n){2,}', text)
result = [par for par in pars if any(par.startswith(p) for p in li)]
```

Here,

- `re.split(r'(?:\r?\n){2,}', text)` splits the `text` with two or more (`{2,}`) occurrences of an optional CR and then LF
- `[par for par in pars if any(par.startswith(p) for p in li)]` keeps only those `par`s that start with any item in `li`.